# MySQL Table Setup

Tags: php, mysql

Hey all,
I am setting up a PHP web app that will make use of subdomains for accounts. I am storing subdomains in a MySQL table with the following fields:

```
subdomain_id | owner_id | name | date_created
```

owner_id maps back to user_id in the user table The user table has the following fields:

```
user_id | email_address | etc...
```

Now I am trying to figure out what is the best way to store which users have access to which subdomain. Is the best to set up another table with the following fields?

```
id | subdomain_id | user_id
```

That would contain data such as the following (showing user #6 has access to subdomains 4 & 7):

```
id | sudomain_id | user_id
1  | 4           | 6
2  | 4           | 23
3  | 7           | 6
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way to model a many-to-many relationship, but the `id` column is entirely unnecessary. You don't need to give every table an artificial identifier. The primary key of that table is simply `(subdomain_id, user_id)`.

Comment: I agree with Dan to a certain extent.  Surrogate keys are often not necessary but are not a bad practices, especially if that table's role grows to more than just a relation table in the future.  Perhaps permissions will be attached to a user's access to a subdomain in the future, then this table will need to have a 1 to many relationship with a permission table.  If I were you, I would leave the surrogate key in the table.

Comment: @Zoidberg agreed. I intend to leave the surrogate key, but understand what Dan was getting at.

Comment: if this answer is satisfactory, be sure to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Zoidberg will do, giving me a 6minute wait time to accept however.

Comment: I did not know that, learn something new every day, good luck with your database design